# Google Docs get the number of collaborators currently editing at given time

Tags: regex, api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I would like to know, if it's possible to get access to the **number of collaborators currently editing a google doc**.

My account owns the document and editing is enabled for the public.

I'm thinking along these lines:

1) Google Docs API - I have tried to find something in it, but maybe I'm not looking at the right stuff. Does anyone have experience if something like what I need is achievable?

2) Access the Doc through a command line browser (and somehow authorizing - any idea how?) and just pulling the whole HTML tree and then parsing the HTML with regex to find the specific number I'm looking for, then make it into a cron job running every hour for example.

Any feedback much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Google Docs API - I have tried to find something in it, but maybe I'm not looking at the right stuff. Does anyone have experience if something like what I need is achievable?

No clue on this yet.

> 2) Access the Doc through a command line browser (and somehow authorizing - any idea how?) and just pulling the whole HTML tree and then parsing the HTML with regex to find the specific number I'm looking for, then make it into a cron job running every hour for example.

[GoogleCL](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) sounds like what you want. It will allow you to edit/delete/create/download/upload Google Docs (and by the looks of it, SO much more) from the command line. From there, you can probably port this doc to your local computer and do whatever you want to it.

[Some documentation/examples for GoogleCL Docs](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/ExampleScripts#Docs)

For example,

`google docs get "Super Cool Doc" superlocaldoc.txt`

For authentication, it seems like GoogleCL [opens a browser](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/ConfigurationOptions) to authenticate each Google service (Docs, Calendar, etc.), but it claims you only have to do so once (once per session? once per full moon? who knows).